# `awk` - define number of digits in exponent when using scientific notation

Tags: awk, printf, gawk

I have input data using scientific notation as in (TAB-separated)

```
-2.60000000E-001        -2.84200000E-011        1.00000000E+000 2.45060000E-010 0.00000000E+000 -1.98000000E-012
```

using `awk`, I'm extracting some column and do a mathematical operation on another. To make sure that the format is as needed, printf is applied:

```
awk '{ printf "%9.8E\t%9.8E\n", $1,sqrt($4) }' infile.dat
```

However in my output the number of digits for the exponent changes from 3 to 2:

```
-3.00000000E-01 1.90446843E-05
```

How do I define these in the printf statement, so that I get the desired output:

```
-3.00000000E-001 1.90446843E-005
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

printf uses the stdio and this does not provide a way to set the exponent length. So you need to run your own.

```
awk 'BEGIN{
  v="-3.00000000E-01 " 
  v=gensub("E([+-])([0-9][0-9]) ","E\\10\\2","",v )
  print v
  exit}'
```

This puts the value into variable v, then applies a substitution to search for the exponent, and if it is on 2 positions, it adds a 0. If it is already on 3 positions, nothing is added.

gensub is only available in gawk

Comment: Well, I had a `sed` workaround (`sed -E 's/E-?/&0/g'`) but was hoping for a direct command. Obviously impossible as you stated.